# Interpreting cv2.imencode result

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg

What is buffer returned by `cv2.imencode` represent?

Here is example for 1x1 pix image.

```
import cv2
impor numpy as np

img= np.zeros((1,1,3),np.uint8)
en= cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
print type(en)
<type 'tuple'>
print en[1].shape
(631, 1)
```

For some reason size of buffer not changed when the size of image changed:

```
img= np.zeros((10,10,3),np.uint8)
en= cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
en[1].shape
(631, 1)
```

Update: it's have different size for bigger image.

```
img= np.zeros((1000,1000,3),np.uint8)
en= cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
en[1].shape
(16503, 1)
```

With random data:

```
img= (np.random.rand(1,1,3)*255).astype(np.uint8)
en= cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
en[1].shape
(634, 1)

img= (np.random.rand(10,10,3)*255).astype(np.uint8)
en= cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
en[1].shape
(899, 1)

img= (np.random.rand(1000,1000,3)*255).astype(np.uint8)
en= cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
en[1].shape
(1175962, 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [`cv2.imencode`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode) documentation

> Note: cvEncodeImage returns single-row matrix of type CV_8UC1 that
>   contains encoded image as array of bytes.

So basically the output depends upon the image format you define `.png`, `.jpg`, etc, each format has it's own serilization conventions and `cv2.imencode` does precisely that. It also contains some meta-data related to that image format, ex: compression level, etc. along with pixel data.

Comment: That doesn't make it any clearer.  The result is two-dimensional, which is weird.  I just want to get a bytes object to include in a larger message to be written across the network and then converted by into an image by a non-python program.

Comment: I tried to save the buffer returned from cv2.imencode into a binary file, but the file is twice the one saved directly via cv2.imsave. Are there any functions that I can use to compress the buffer before saving it to a binary file?

Comment: You can always write the output from `cv2.imwrite()` to a binary file using: `with open("name.bin", "wb") as f: f.write(buffer_from_imwrite)`

Answer (score 2):

In-memory manipulation is a little less than documented in the introductory tutorials, and most advice online directs you to write to disk and then read from the disk.

Alternately, what you may be trying to do is create an in memory representation for sending to video, or off to a database, or ... disks are not the only places they go.

Your original code creates an in-memory buffer that has not been interpreted by CV2. This is equivalent to `imwrite`

```
img= (np.random.rand(1000,1000,3)*255).astype(np.uint8)
en = cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
```

When written to disk results in a 1-pixel wide JPEG. To have CV2 correctly interpret the data, you need to decode it (equivalent to `imread`)

```
de = cv2.imdecode(en,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

This causes CV2 to correctly interpret the data in such a way as to make it suitable for writing to image files, frames, or video.

```
cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',de)
video.write(de)
```

Comment: [`cv2.imencode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) returns two values, the first being whether the operation is successful and the second being the encoded image. `en` in your first code snippet would be tuple. For `cv2.imdecode()` to work, you need to use `en[1]` instead of `en`.